# "403 Forbidden nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu) "

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, http-status-code-403

I have configured nginx with multiple locations, one for a laravel project and another for a native php project.
Laravel project is working perfectly, but the second location seems to give:

> "403 Forbidden nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu) "

Here is my default file:

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        root /var/www/html/washyapi/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php$is_args$args;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        server_name 167.71.239.178;
        location / {
        try_files   $uri $uri/  index.php$is_args$args;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        #index index.php;       
        }
        location /admin {
        root /var/www/html/;
        #autoindex on;
        #autoindex_exact_size off;
        index index.php;
        #try_files $uri  /index.php?$query_string;      
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

        location /phpmyadmin {
           root /usr/share/;
           index index.php index.html index.htm;
           location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                   try_files $uri =404;
                   root /usr/share/;
                   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                   fastcgi_index index.php;
                   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
           }
           location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                   root /usr/share/;
           }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

after few days of struggling, here what i have done to make it work.
Here's the working configuration to have two apps working, where one application exists in a subdirectory of another.
default file :

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /var/www/top/public;

index index.html index.htm index.php;

server_name _;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /nested {
    alias /var/www/nested/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @nested;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}

location @nested {
    rewrite /nested/(.*)$ /nested/index.php?/$1 last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
```

}

don't forget to restart the nginx server :

```
service nginx restart
```